# retrieve data from mysql db through ksoap2

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am supposed to retrieve data from mysql database at server from
android mobile. I guess ksoap2 api would be suitable for it. I tried
a lot, but found the enhanced copies of API's. Please refer me to the
proper link of ksoap2 API, and also how to retrieve data.

Comment: http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ ?

Answer (score 0):

if the output is in xml format,You can use Ksoap2.If your output is a  json object,then better  use JSON parsing.

Are you using webservice  with php/mysql?

Which format the response is coming?

Comment: plz tell me how is conneting mysql database through ksoap2 webservices..already am searched various forums and google search...but i can't understand.help me..send me some step by step tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to get all users from webservice,then

```
public  String getAllUsers(String key)


 {

 dbase=new DatabaseActivity(this.adapterContext);


    String methodName = "GetUsers";


    SoapObject sUsers = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);

    sUsers.addProperty("sKey", key);
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(

            SoapEnvelope.VER11);





    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(sUsers);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;


    Users theUser = null;

    try {

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodName, envelope);



        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

 //---------------parse this result     

     }
```

Here Namespace is  your webservice url and method name is the function you want to access.

Comment: am having one error in my emulator...ERROR: java.net.ConnectException:/192.168.1.249:8080 connection refused.y dis error is cuming.plz help me